# Update Wordpress theme so navigation bar is not fixed to top of webpage

Tags: wordpress

I would like to update a Wordpress theme so that the navigation menu is not fixed to the top of the page (i.e. I don't want to be able to see the bar when I scroll down). The default for the theme I have chosen is a fixed navigation menu. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual code will depend on your theme, but you can try something similar to this:

```
#main-header {
  position: relative;
};
```

And then you'll need to set the z-index and push it to the top, like this:

```
#main-header {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9999;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Check the id of your nav bar and change it as necessary. Note, you'll need to change this in your theme's CSS, or even better, in your own child theme.